# time series in r: how to merge two dataframes by two keys, but only generating one column

Tags: r, merge, time-series

I´m doing a job about time-series in r and I need to insert missing rows in a regular time series. The initial data frame is :

```
            DIA HORA CPU_SEC
 345 01/01/2015    7      10
1485 02/01/2015    7       5
5632 05/01/2015    7       5
7071 06/01/2015    7       5
8289 07/01/2015    7       5
9706 08/01/2015    7       5
```

And my idea is to fill this data frame with extra rows (the missing hours for everyday) in other data frame initialized to `0` in `CPU_SEC` column

```
         DIA HORA CPU_SEC
1 01/01/2015    1       0
2 01/01/2015    2       0
3 01/01/2015    3       0
4 01/01/2015    4       0
5 01/01/2015    5       0
6 01/01/2015    6       0
7 01/01/2015    7       0
```

And finally, merging both and having only a `CPU_SEC` column but if two records have the same key, then the first data frame must win. I´m using this code but the result is two columns

`DF_final <- merge(DF_reducido,DF_zero,by=c("DIA","HORA"),all = TRUE)`

```
         DIA HORA CPU_SEC.x CPU_SEC.y
1 01/01/2015    1        NA         0
2 01/01/2015    2        NA         0
3 01/01/2015    3        NA         0
4 01/01/2015    4        NA         0
5 01/01/2015    5        NA         0
6 01/01/2015    6        NA         0
7 01/01/2015    7        10         0
```

help, please...

Comment: Option 1) drop "CPU_SEC" from `DF_zero` before the merge, then merge, then replace NAs with zeros.  Option 2) leave your code as is and create a new column `DF_final$CPU_SEC <- ifelse(is.na(DF_final$CPU_SEC.x), CPU_SEC.y, CPU_SEC.x)`

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways to do it, but if you already have `DF_final` and it looks right to you, you can always just use `dplyr` and mutate them together.

```
DF_final <- DF_final %>%
    mutate(CPU_SEC = ifelse(is.na(CPU_SEC.x), CPU_SEC.y, CPU_SEC.x)) %>%
    select(-CPU_SEC.x, -CPU_SEC.y)
```

Probably better ways to start the problem, but if you're just about there anyway in your last data frame, this is an easy solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your different ideas, I prefered use the  column dropping method and afterwards change the na rows by zero.